# Fancy Header Chapter Thumb - Change boxed text to display Subsections in two lines

Tags: sectioning, chapterthumb

In the code given below, I wanted to change the text that appears in the Chapter Thumb to display the current Subsections Titles.  Currently, the chapter thumb shows the chapter name.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{ultramarine}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}}

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{mybluei} \rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{mybluei}\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape LF Foot}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries CTR FOOT}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape RT Foot}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap 1 Problems}
\section{Problem 1}
\subsection{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 1}
\lipsum[1-7]
\newpage
\section{Problem 2}
\subsection{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 2}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Chap 2 Problems}
\section{Problem 1}
\subsection{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\subsection{Solution 1}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\section{Problem 2}
\subsection{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 2}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Can you assist me in getting the current subsections to display in the chapter thumbs?  For example, under `\section{Problem 1}`, I wanted to display

- Line 1 - Problem 1
- Line 2 - Solution 1

in the chapter thumb.  Then for the next section (Problem 2), to display Problem 2, Solution 2 and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{ultramarine}

%\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}}

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}

\def\subsectiontitle{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}

\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{mybluei} \rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
   \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{mybluei}\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \subsectiontitle}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape LF Foot}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries CTR FOOT}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape RT Foot}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap 1 Problems}
\section{Problem 1}
\subsection{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 1}
\lipsum[1-7]
\newpage
\section{Problem 2}
\subsection{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 2}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Chap 2 Problems}
\section{Problem 1}
\subsection{Problem 1}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\subsection{Solution 1}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\section{Problem 2}
\subsection{Problem 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Solution 2}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]