# Insert pages with just the headers and footers

Tags: header-footer

This post is building from the code developed by Gonzalo Medina found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263788/fancy-header-chapter-thumb-change-boxed-text-to-display-subsections-in-two-lin).  I wanted to add some pages to my document that would just contain the headers and footers and sidethumb.  When I tried the example found [here to insert a blank page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/add-a-new-empty-page), I do not get the header and footer and sidethumb (as the post mentioned).  Can you assist me to add pages with just the headers and footers and sidethumb?

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{ultramarine}{RGB}{0,45,97}
    \definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \pagestyle{plain}

    \newcounter{chapshift}
    \addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

    \newcommand\BoxColor{ultramarine}

    \usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \def\subsectiontitle{}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\def\subsectiontitle{#1}}

    \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\textcolor{mybluei} \rightmark%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
        text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
      at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
      {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
       \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \subsectiontitle}}}};
      \end{tikzpicture}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\textcolor{mybluei}\leftmark%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
        text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
      at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
      {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
        \centering\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\scshape\rightmark \\ \subsectiontitle}}}};
      \end{tikzpicture}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
    \addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
    \newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
    \addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.5pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape LF Foot}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries CTR FOOT}
    \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape RT Foot}

    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
      \fancyhf{}
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    }

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
    \clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \fi}
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
      {\vskip 40\p@}
      {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Chap 1 Problems}
    \section{Problem 1}
    \subsection{Problem 1}
    \lipsum[1-7]
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\thispagestyle{empty}` sets the page style to `empty` i.e. no headers or footers.

If you *want* headers and footers, you don't want `empty`. So just delete `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the relevant pages.